# problem with swip gesture recognizers in iOS

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, swipe

I am using the following code :

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = 
   [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
   initWithTarget:self 
   action:@selector(swipeDetected:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];
```

And,

```
- (void)swipeDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
}
```

But I dont  see any output when I swipe in the simulator. Can anyone please help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: @PengOne : I have a table view ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `UITableView`, it may be blocking the action. Try adding the `swipeGesture` directly to the `tableView`.

Comment: well, i still couldnt get it to work, but kind of better than before !...thanks for the suggestions !